# Weird NSMutable Array error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am simply just trying to update my score in the 'score' nsmutable array which was defined in the (id) type function called when my app is run. So I have no clue what is going wrong, I put in a NSLog before the body of the function and after to check what is happening and I will post them after the code.

```
-(void)changeScore:(int)moves AtLevel:(int)theLevel{
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    NSLog(@"At level %d we have a score of: %d ", i+1, [[scores objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
}
if (theLevel <= 9){
    NSNumber* number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:50 - moves];
    [scores replaceObjectAtIndex:theLevel - 1 withObject:number];
    NSLog(@"this is number's int value: %d and this is thelevel - 1: %d", [number intValue], theLevel - 1);
}
if (theLevel > 9 && theLevel <= 19){
    NSNumber* number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:150-moves];
    [scores replaceObjectAtIndex:theLevel - 1 withObject:number];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    NSLog(@"At level %d we have a score of: %d", i+1, [[scores objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
}
}
```

and the NSLog produces this:

```
2012-04-14 14:53:49.018 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 1 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.022 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 2 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.023 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 3 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.024 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 4 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.026 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 5 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.027 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 6 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.028 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 7 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.029 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 8 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.030 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 9 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.031 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 10 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.032 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 11 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.033 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 12 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.035 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 13 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.036 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 14 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.101 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 15 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.102 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 16 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.103 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 17 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.104 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 18 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.104 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 19 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.105 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 20 we have a score of: 0 
2012-04-14 14:53:49.106 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] this is number's int value: 38 and this is thelevel - 1: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.111 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 1 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.112 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 2 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.113 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 3 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.114 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 4 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.114 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 5 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.135 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 6 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.136 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 7 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.137 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 8 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.138 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 9 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.157 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 10 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.159 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 11 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.160 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 12 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.160 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 13 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.163 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 14 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.165 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 15 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.166 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 16 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.167 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 17 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.169 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 18 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.170 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 19 we have a score of: 0
2012-04-14 14:53:49.171 Arctic Defender[2068:f803] At level 20 we have a score of: 0
```

EDIT: this is my score initalize code:

```
-(id)initNewScores{
//Initalize 20 levels
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    NSNumber* numb = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
    [scores addObject:numb];
    [numb release];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show the value of `scores` on entry to that method.  I bet it is `nil`.   I.e. whatever you are using to initialize that mutable array isn't working.

Comment: But I just called objectAtIndex on all 20 indices, wouldn't I get an error if it was nil?

Comment: No, messages sent to nil result in nil. If this wasn't the case, all of Cocoa would explode in a big fireball

Comment: Elementary mistake which even experienced programmers do, forgetting to initialise their arrays... Always look for the simple solution first! (myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init])

Comment: @PeterP In Cocoa, messages sent to `nil` don't return errors — they're usually just no-ops, and always return 'falsy' values (`nil`, `0`, `NO`). Messaging `nil` is a feature of Cocoa, and won't throw exceptions or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks guys, just allocing and initing my array worked, thanks, I totally wasnt thinking that my array was nil beause it was supposed to be initalized as all 0. Thanks